# Action when new value is entered into certain column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a DB table that has new records inserted via an import from a log file. I would like to write a job that sends an alert when a specific new field was enterd. As of now I have been checking to see the number of unique entries in that field and when it increases of a set value, I get the alert. The problem is that each time I need to go back and update the count in the query. So just wondering if there is another way to do this.

```
Declare @count as int 
select @count = count(clientkey) from QueryData group by clientkey
If @@ROWCOUNT > 18

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='DB Admin',
    @recipients = 'joe@mail.com',
    @copy_recipients = 'pete@mail.com',
    @subject = 'GPDB Warning',
    @body = 'A new clientkey is being used in the QueryData table'
```

Appreciate any response

EDIT:

Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QueryData](
[ImportDate] [datetime] NULL,
[clientKey] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[QueryTerms] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[LastSearchDate] [datetime] NULL,
[QueryActivity]  AS (datediff(day,[UpdatedDate],[LastSearchDate])) PERSISTED,
[ImportMethod] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[PowerField] [nvarchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

So when the import occurs the importdate is updated and the updatedDate field is also updated. The clientKey field is the one that concerns me and there can be multiple rows for a clientkey but I need to know when a new key is inserted that has not been already inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an instead of trigger. The only complication is that you have to repeat the `INSERT`...

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.QueryData_NewClientKey
ON dbo.QueryData
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted AS i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QueryData AS q
    ON i.clientkey = q.clientkey
    WHERE q.clientkey IS NULL
  )
  BEGIN
    -- send your e-mail here
  END

  INSERT dbo.QueryData(column1, columns2, etc.)
    SELECT column1, column2, etc. FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

With an after trigger, you need to be able to differentiate between rows that you just inserted into the table, and rows that existed before, so the logic is slightly more complicated. Assuming you have a primary key on the table, you can say:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.QueryData_NewClientKey
ON dbo.QueryData
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.QueryData AS new_data
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON new_data.key = i.key
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.QueryData AS old_data
    ON i.clientkey = old_data.clientkey
    AND i.key <> old_data.key
    WHERE old_data.key IS NULL
  )
  BEGIN
    -- send your e-mail
  END
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your response very helpful. Before I implement,just wanted to add that I have a date column that is updated when the auto import happens so can I apply to the second suggestion above (after trigger)

Comment: @vbNewbie why, do you set the date value yourself? Do you know that all of the rows found in the trigger will be greater than any row in the table? Does your table not have a primary key?

Comment: I don't actually. Someone else handles the import but the date is automatically updated when the file import happens. the table does not have a primary key. I will add the structure of the table above

Comment: I think you should just use the `INSTEAD OF` trigger. Without a primary key, relying on the date being newer seems brittle to me.